# add a value to a json body request in python

Tags: python, json, api, rest

I have created my own function which i import called timestamp, it returns two values :

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests
import json


def timeframe():
    response = requests.get("https://$host/api/profiler/1.13/reporting/timestamps.json", verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("admin", "admin"))
    time = response.json()
    for entry in time:
        if entry.get('data_resolution') == 'min':
            if entry.get('datasource') == 'FDS_TRAFFIC':
                start_time = entry['start_time']
                end_time = entry['end_time']
                return start_time, end_time

timeframe()
```

i need to add timestamps to a keys in a json body request, you will see 'end' & 'start' keys. I need to retrieve those timestamps and somehow add them to those keys.

```
    import requests
import timestamp
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

stamp = timestamp.timeframe()

print(stamp)

url = 'http://10.65.170.112/api/profiler/1.12/reporting/reports'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
payload = {
    "criteria": {
        "time_frame": {
            "start": str(stamp[0]),
            "end": str(stamp[1]),
            "resolution": "flow"
        },
        "query": {
            "realm": "traffic_flow_list",
            "sort_column": 41,
            "devices": [
        {
          "ipaddr": "10.65.170.2"
        }
      ],
            "group_by": "flw",
            "columns": [
                729,
                40,
                41,
                14,
                44,
                10,
                45,
                46
            ]
        }
    },
    "template_id": 184
}

req = requests.post(url,  headers=headers, data = payload, verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('admin', 'admin'),)

print(req.status_code, req.text)
```

Not sure what to do.

Thanks

Comment: what is your question exactly? can you explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: @komatiraju032 you will see on the body, "end" and "start" which need to be filed with data, this a POST request, you will see too i import timestamp(which is the exact time stamp i need to fill in ) not sure how can i  fit in, that fuction on to the body

Comment: you can try `"end": timestamps[1]` and `"start": timestamps[0]`

Comment: @komatiraju032 thanks man, but it didnt work, i mean i get HTTP 200 put some how its not accepting the value so when it returns the response i dont get what i am looking for.

Comment: what is the output of `timestamp.timeframe()`

Comment: The output is unix timestamp, but from a remote machine. so the ouput wil be 2 values with a min of diffrence

Comment: then why it's not working are you getting any error?

Comment: I get a 200 code, and then i should get a response which will contain a report id. but i am not getting that response, so i am assuming it as to do with the time stamps, because if put them in manually i can post and the retrieve the report id

Comment: the response i get is the log in page of the remote machine. but in html

Comment: try converting the timestamp to string

Comment: as : str(function()) ?

Comment: like this `"end": str(timestamps[1]) and "start": str(timestamps[0])`

Comment: unfortunately was not succesfull, i used postman and posted the timestamps manually which gave me the id i was looking for, so i am not sure how can i automate thi timestamp thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you created returns a tuple: `return start_time, end_time`.

So, a way to implement would be:

`start, end = timestamp.timeframe()`

Then, you can hydrate your body:

```
body = {  
    "criteria": {  
        "time_frame": {  
            "end": end,  
            "start": start,  
            "resolution": "flow" 
},
```

Comment: Ola Raphael, fucionou , mas , nao funcionou, ou seja, ele devolve HTTP 200, mas o report que percisa de ser gerado nao e aceite por cause dos parametros nao serem inseridos. resumindo. ele ate funciona mas ele nao esta a aceitar os timestamps que perciso

Comment: Ola Alexandre. 
Entao, o problema nao esta no "assignment of values", mas sim aqui: `time = response.json()`

Voce poderia confirmar qual e o output do `response.json()`?

Comment: I saw in a different post of yours that the response is:

```
[
    {
        "data_resolution": "min",
        "datasource": "TRAFFIC",
        "end_time": 1591793520,
        "start_time": 0
    },
    {
        "data_resolution": "day",
        "datasource": "TRAFFIC",
        "end_time": 1591743600,
        "start_time": 0
    },
]
```

Naturally, you're looking for this index:

```
{
        "data_resolution": "min",
        "datasource": "FDS_TRAFFIC",
        "end_time": 1591793520,
        "start_time": 1587220140
    },
```

Comment: Your script works when I run it locally. I replaced your `time` variable (on your timeframe() method) with the json response. And I get the following: start: 1587220140 and end: 1591793520.

Comment: Hi Rafa, Thanks, but i cannot past the json reponse and assign it to TIME, as thos timestamps are update every min, so i need to query first get the reponse and from that extract the values i need

Comment: And thank you again. I think the problem may be something else, because i can perfom the POST on Postman and get 201, but when i run the script locally i am not getting a 201, but instead a 200

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import timestamp
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import urllib3
import json
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

stamp = timestamp.timeframe()
auth = HTTPBasicAuth("admin", "admin")

url = "https://$host/api/profiler/1.13/reporting/reports"

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

payload = {
    "criteria": {
        "time_frame": {
            "start": stamp[0],
            "end": stamp[1],
            "resolution": "flow"
        },
        "query": {
            "realm": "traffic_summary",
            "sort_column": 41,
            "devices": [{ "ipaddr": "10.65.170.2"}],
            "group_by": "hos",
            "columns": [
                729,
                40,
                41,
                14,
                44,
                10,
                45,
                46
            ]
        }
    },
    "template_id": 184
}

req = requests.post(url, verify=False, auth=auth, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))

print(req.headers)
```

Was resolved by adding data=json.dump(payload)